PWA project help. Users who have installed it jump to the application to open it
PWA project help. Users who have installed it jump to the application to open it. I try to use **function isPwa() { return window.matchMedia('(display-mode: standalone)').matches }   **
Determine whether pwa has been installed. As a result, no matter how you change the browser or install pwa, it will return felse. This is why I want users who have installed it to click on Facebook's installation link and jump directly to the starting address of pwa. If they have installed it, The user clicks the pwa download link again using Facebook to directly open my manifest.json in the application like this.
"start_url": "./index2.html", "display": "standalone", "display_Override": [ "window-controls-overlay" ], "edge_side_panel": { "preferred_width": 496 }, "background_color": "#ffffff", "theme_color": "#000000", "related_applications": [ { "platform": "webapp", "url": "https://googleplay.bh0casino.site/game_lp721/manifest.json" } ],
I tried changing many browsers, mobile phones and computers. The value of isPWA() is the same whether it is installed or not.I hope that Facebook users who click on my PWA download link have installed PWA. If they have installed it, they will jump directly to the PWA application to open it instead of accessing the download address in the browser or jumping to the PWA start address in the browser.
